# Preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex, templates

I want to replace content from a string which is contained within {*content*}. It an be multilines etc. The preg_replace function should remove the whole 
{ *com
no mat
ment*
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preg_match_all('/{*([^}]+*)}/s'), $content, $matches)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\{[^}]*\}/s', 'replacement content', $subject);
```

Comment: Whats the difference between yours and the one above. both are working

Comment: The author seems to want the {} replaced too, so this looks good to me. The round brackets are unnecessary though. +1

Comment: Agreed about the round brackets, fixed!

Comment: @Highly Irregular I thought so too, but it turned out they didn't *(see comments on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011566/preg-replace-in-php/5011610#5011610)).

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\{).+?(?=\})/s', '', $str);
```

[See it](http://codepad.org/GQSUJcQi).

Comment: whats the difference between yours and the one below. Both are working

Comment: @user381595 These answers don't have floating sort order, so please link to the one in question. The one I assume you are talking about, they are very similar, except mine use ungreedy match instead of explicitly looking for closing character, and mine must have at least one char between `{` and `}`. Mine also doesn't have an unnecessary capturing group, unless you want to reuse the captured text :)

Comment: i am sorry but this is supposed to be removing {*comment*} but i just realized that it removes everything between {}. I am sorry for the inconvienience but could you please modify it so it only removes the {asterisk comment asterisk}

Comment: @user381595 Sure, see update. I think this is what you want - it doesn't consume the asterisk, so `{something}` will be replaced with `{}`.

Comment: @user381595 Why did you unaccept this... is it no longer what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```
preg_match_all('/\{([^}]+\)}/s'), $content, $matches)
```

You need the `s` modifier to make the expression work with newlines. The `$matches` array will contain all the matching segments which you can then replace.